# when i run this code,i see: **invalid syntax in "else"**

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a new Python programmer and when i run this code in idle python,i see: **invalid syntax in "else"**

```
 def rloan(principal, annual_interest_rate, duration , number_of_payments):
        r = annual_interest_rate/(12*100)
        n = duration*12
        p = number_of_payments
        
        if r>0 :
            remain = (principal*((1+r)**n-(1+r)**p)/((1+r)**n-1)
        else:    
            remain = principal*(1-(p/n))
        return remain
    print(rloan(1000.0,4.5,5,12))
```

I'm probably missing something very simple; however, I haven't been able to find the answer on my own, please help me

Comment: Check the brackets in the first line, I think you missed a )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close a bracket.

```
remain = (principal*((1+r)**n-(1+r)**p)/((1+r)**n-1))
```

Correct this line and it should work.

Edit:

I think your print statement is also not indented properly.

Here is a working code:

```
def rloan(principal, annual_interest_rate, duration , number_of_payments):
        r = annual_interest_rate/(12*100)
        n = duration*12
        p = number_of_payments
        
        if r>0 :
            remain = (principal*((1+r)**n-(1+r)**p)/((1+r)**n-1))
        else:    
            remain = principal*(1-(p/n))
        return remain
print(rloan(1000.0,4.5,5,12))
```